# Getting to Salou from Barcelona airport

Tags: airport-transfer, spain, transportation, bcn

I’m going to Salou in July, flying into Barcelona. What are my options for getting to Salou from the airport, and how can I decide among them? Are taxis at the airport reasonable or do I need to prebook? We'll be six people so may not fit in one taxi.

Comment: Six people is more than one taxi. "Reasonable" is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: What research have you done up to now?

Comment: Bear in mind this is roughly an hour's trip. Is there nothing into Reus (which is on the outskirts of Salou)?

Answer (score 2):

- Taxi might be an option, however be sure to get a taxi-van: regular taxis can carry no more than 4 passengers, probably 3 because many drivers might refuse to allow using the front seat as for COVID
- Salou used to have a railway station, but the line was closed early 2020 when it was diverted inland. There is a station near Port Aventura that might or might not be convenient to you, but has poor service. Another option would be Vila-seca station, on the main line between Tarragona and Reus. For these, you will need to change on Barcelona Sants railway station.
- Buses on the area are run by Plana, which is known to offer a poor service. Not sure if there's any direct route from Barcelona airport.

Comment: The secondary source [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Barcelona/Salou) indicates the Plana bus runs every 4 hours, takes 1 hr 43 minutes, and does stop at El Prat Airport. The [Plana Bus website](https://www.busplana.com/en) says the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is the bus schedule and it's current: https://empresaplana.cat/uploads/boxes-lineas-configuration/horario-temporada-alta-del-01052022-al-01112022-2.pdf I am a little bit unsure what the problem is, really.

Answer (score 1):

Hire a private minivan.

It will have space for the 6 of you and all your luggage.